# Toggle Drop Down List Stays Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with the toggle down menu or list in my case.

The problem is that the menu is always open (the #text_box) when I load the page.

It should be closed so when the user clicks on the 'Open Me' button then will open.

I have put the codes on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1r29v8tj/1/) and here it does not work at all, it does not open or close. I have copied all the necessary code parts: html, css, javascript.

The main problem is in the starting state when I open the page in a browser the menu/list is always open.

Also I'm making it to be responsive for desktop, tablets and mobiles.
Can you help me fix the problem? Thanks

HTML:

```
<button  onclick="toggle_visibility('text_box');">Open Me</button>
<div id="text_box"> 
<ul >
        <li>Test_1</li>
        <li>Test_2</li>
        <li>Test_3</li>
        <li>Test_4</li>
        <li>Test_5</li>

</ul>        

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {

   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

CSS:

```
 button {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 background: #4479BA;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: solid 1px #20538D;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
 }

 button:hover {
 background: #356094;
 border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

 button:active {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 background: #2E5481;
 border: solid 1px #203E5F;

 }


 #text_box {
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 0px; 
 padding: 2px 0px;
 background:rgba(102,102,102,1);
 color: #fff;

 }
```

Comment: Check out my answer, it might help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I found every answer helpful. I will have to implement the solution from @divy3993 because I have already been using javascript. I will also start learning and implementing JQuery because it's easy and interesting. I will use it for my next project. Thank you all! :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do so **better way prioritized** below:

**CSS**

```
 #foo { display:none;}
```

[JSFiddle : CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/1r29v8tj/10/)

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.display ="none"; /* JavaScript Solution*/
```

[JSFiddle : JS](https://jsfiddle.net/1r29v8tj/2/)

**OR**

**JQuery**

```
$("#foo").hide();
```

> **Note:** If you are using JQuery solution do not forget to add JQuery Library

[JSFiddle : JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/1r29v8tj/7/)

**Solution:**

```js
document.getElementById("foo").style.display ="none";
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
 button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #4479BA;
    color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
button:hover {
    background: #356094;
    border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #2E5481;
    border: solid 1px #203E5F;
 
}


#foo {
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 0px; 
 padding: 2px 0px;
    background:rgba(102,102,102,1);
    color: #fff;
 
  }
```

```html
<button  onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Open Me</button>
<div id="foo"> 
    <ul >
         <li>Test_1</li>
            <li>Test_2</li>
            <li>Test_3</li>
            <li>Test_4</li>
            <li>Test_5</li>
           
    </ul>        

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start off with setting the div to display:none.

This way it will always start off as none.

You could also explore jQuery as an option.

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" name="answer" />

$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#myDiv').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start your div with `display: none` in the CSS.

Like this :

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```css
 button {
     padding: 10px 15px;
     background: #4479BA;
     color: #FFF;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: solid 1px #20538D;
     text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
     -webkit-user-select:none;
     -moz-user-select:none;
     -ms-user-select:none;
     user-select:none;
 }
 button:hover {
     background: #356094;
     border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 button:active {
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     background: #2E5481;
     border: solid 1px #203E5F;
 }
 #text_box {
     width: 200px;
     margin-top: 0px;
     padding: 2px 0px;
     background:rgba(102, 102, 102, 1);
     color: #fff;
     display: none;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle_visibility('text_box');">Open Me</button>
<div id="text_box">
    <ul>
        <li>Test_1</li>
        <li>Test_2</li>
        <li>Test_3</li>
        <li>Test_4</li>
        <li>Test_5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start learning JQuery. It makes these things so much easier, and is fast becoming the standard way of doing things. It might seem like hocus pocus if you are just getting started with JavaScript. But it will save you a lot of time and headaches when doing the simple stuff. Not to mention keystrokes.

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/1r29v8tj/9/

**HTML**

```
<button id="dropper">Open Me</button>
<div id="foo">
    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li>Test_1</li>
        <li>Test_2</li>
        <li>Test_3</li>
        <li>Test_4</li>
        <li>Test_5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#dropper').on('click', function(){
    $('#dropdown').toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#dropdown {
    margin: 2px 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

For what it's worth, I would just toggle the `ul`, but it depends on what you are trying to do.

Also, look into the bootstrap library, which has a lot of slick dropdown classes that are very versatile and mobile-friendly.

Comment: I found your solution very helpful and I got motivation to explore and learn more about JQuery and start using bootstrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

update your style of `#text_box` to following

```
#text_box {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    padding: 2px 0px;
    background:rgba(102,102,102,1);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
}
```

I have just added `display:none` in it.